# Regex to validate and extract data from string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to create 2 regex in .net c#.

1. Validate that the input that the user writes has the following format one or multiple times:

Sample:

```
/TEXT;dd-mm-yyyy;TEXT/TEXT;dd-mm-yyyy;TEXT/TEXT;dd-mm-yyyy;TEXT
```

Or

```
/TEXT;dd-mm-yyyy;TEXT
```

At least 1 time should be entered.
The middle part: dd-mm-yyyy should be day-month-year like 20-02-1997
In the parts TEXT there shouldn't be any / otherwise i accept that regex willfail.

2. The second regex would be to extract the "groups".

I tried with:

```
string test = "/TEXT;dd-mm-yyyy;TEXT/TEXT;dd-mm-yyyy;TEXT/TEXT;dd-mm-yyyy;TEXT";
            string reguexp = "[\\/(\\w+;\\w+;\\w+)+]";
            foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(test, reguexp))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", match.Value, match.Index);
            }
```

However is not working as detects each character as a match and i would like to extract "groups" `/TEXT;dd-mm-yyyy;TEXT` one by one to later do any extra data process.

I tried to start with the second regex thinking that once i have this regex the other should be easier.

Any help is accepted.
Best regards

Comment: `Regex` is not a good means to validate *dates*, just think on *leap year*, `28/29 Feb` etc.: `29-02-2016` or `30-03-2016` are OK when `29-02-2017` or `30-02-2016` are not

Comment: I agree with @DmitryBychenko it is not good to validate dates using regex. You could use regex to extract the individual dates and validate them individually

Comment: regex will use groups if you look  each of your match should have a groups property which you can then extract the group and the data within, and then check if valid date etc

Comment: I think something like `\/\w+;\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4};\w+` should do what you need.

Comment: Can "TEXT" parts contain word boundaries? Like whitespace etc?

Comment: @Fildor yes, could contain everything except /

Comment: Have a look at this: https://regex101.com/r/qqkYGZ/1

Comment: @Fildor your example worked for the second regex i need (to extract) however seems that i will need to addapt it to use it with .IsMatch as in my case the patterns need to be complete so should be a /TEXT;dd-mm-yyyy;TEXT and can't be acceptable to introduce for example: /TEXT;dd-mm-yyyy; or /TEXT;;TEXTTEXT;dd-mm-yyyy;TEXT "blocks" should appear or regex IsMatch should return false so i can detect the string doesn't have the proper structure, but you regex i think is a good point of start. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You should use Groups:

```
var strRegex = @"(?<date>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})+";
var myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
var strTargetString = @"01-02-2000;15-03-2018";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
    var dateString = myMatch.Groups["date"].Value;

    // TODO: Check dateString is valid date (e.g. with DateTime.TryParseExact(...))
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what i need is not to validate dates, i want to validate the whole format, is acceptable if a date is not valid just if the pattern match. Also the idea is not a regex for dates, is for the while pattern.